# Why does my styling have unstyled lines in it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pretty-print

I am trying to reproduce the `Tomorrow Night Blue` theme for `code-prettify` as [found here](https://jmblog.github.io/color-themes-for-google-code-prettify/). I have [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tuma24d8/2/). The output looks nothing like in the example and has every other line white. It kinda seems to be applying the style but not really. I have:

```
<body onload="PR.prettyPrint()">
<pre class="prettyprint linenums lang-html">
    &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
    // Say hello world until the user starts questioning
    // the meaningfulness of their existence.
    function helloWorld(world) {
      for (var i = 42; --i &gt;= 0;) {
        alert('Hello ' + String(world));
      }
    }
    &lt;/script&gt;
    &lt;style&gt;
    p { color: pink }
    b { color: blue }
    u { color: &quot;umber&quot; }
    &lt;/style&gt;
</pre>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Code prettify project [is here](https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md#serving-your-own-js--css) and I thought I am following the example.

Comment: fiddle and the code prettify looks same, at-least in chorme.

Comment: *and has every other line white* it's actually `#eee` according to the stylesheet

Comment: They look completely different: https://imgur.com/a/R2HeNrB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the fiddle the css was before the js, so some of the default styles weren't being overwritten. All I had to do was changing the order. Instead of:

```
<link ...tomorrow-night-blue.css">
<link ...prettify.css">
```

Change to:

```
<link ...prettify.css">
<link ...tomorrow-night-blue.css">
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bortao/79cgrkn4/